# How can I make a custom pagination?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Sorry for my English, I have a project in Laravel, and I want to change something in pagination because it shows a lot of page number like this:

[image]

and what I want is:

[image]

but I don't know how to change number of hidden page. the script is:

```
<div class="pagination">
        {{$rows->appends(array_merge(request()->query(),['_ajax'=>1]))->links()}}
    </div>
```

and with inspect element I have:

```html
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="« Previous">
    <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">‹</span>
  </li>
  <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">1</span></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=2">2</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=3">3</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=4">4</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=5">5</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=6">6</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=7">7</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=8">8</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=9">9</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=10">10</a></li>
  <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span class="page-link">...</span></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=15">15</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=16">16</a></li>
  <li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" href="/hotel?start=08%2F04%2F2022&amp;end=08%2F05%2F2022&amp;date=2022-08-04%20-%202022-08-05&amp;adults=1&amp;children=0&amp;_ajax=1&amp;page=2" rel="next" aria-label="Next »">›</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

can someone give a hint? thank you

Comment: What's the point in having `1 ... 15` as pagination options? That makes the pagination links almost entirely pointless. What am I supposed to do if I want to go to page 3?

Comment: ...and what happened to page 16?   Your end-result sample is too limited, eg it looks like you might want a button every 15 pages 1..15..30..45

Comment: if you want to go to page 3 have next and preview page option, i just want not to have a long array of numbers

Comment: In that case a better option would be a dropdown to select the page I want to go to. That way I don't need to click 9 times, and wait for the page to load each time, before I can get to page 10.

Comment: no one now to go directly to page 6, they want to navigate from page to page to see feed. your option is not good

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onEachSide()` method to limit how many button on either side of the current page.

For example, `$users->onEachSide(2)->links()` would look like this:

`<` `1` ... `8` `9` `10` `11` `12` ... `100` `>` if your are on page 10

Another example: `$users->onEachSide(1)->links()` if you are on page 10:

`<` `1` ... `9` `10` `11` ... `100` `>`

However, if this is still not what you want, use can create your own custom by publishing Laravel's pagination helper. Run this on your terminal:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

This will create a blade template in your `view` directory, which you can customize as you wish.

Comment: Thnk you very much for your help i create my own custom